# Is the phone ringing scene from RGV's Company inspired from another movie?

Tags: company

In Ram Gopal Varma's Bollywood film [**Company**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_(film)) (2002), there is a scene where phones all around the world ring to spread the news about the clash between Chandu and Mallik followed by an extensive gang war. That's an extraordinary thought and that's one of the best scenes projecting "Telephone" as a weapon.

Can anybody tell me if there is a movie where Varma could have been inspired by (presentation of the scene and creating the mood with phones ringing)?

**Update:**
I'm unable to find an official clip of that scene. Please feel free to add if you have one. That was a brilliant scene and international moviegoers will love it.

**Update:** 
Here is a clip (from 1:18:12 to 1:19:20) from a dubbed version. I couldn't get the original

**Update:**
You can see a similar scene (climax) in John Wick II (2017)

Comment: "Inspired" ! You mean "Copied" right ?

Comment: Not exactly, Rahul. I can say "Copied" if A Bhatt camp's member (they are not ashamed to even copy a sex scene) or even Mani Ratnam (considering the fact Ratnam had admitted on his unbaked scripts) directed the movie, but calling Ram Gopal Varma's scene a copycat is not appropriate.

Comment: There was a [scene at the end of Lawnmower Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWdlNTrz2oM) where they make all the phones ring.